# Can anybody explain this answer on Codewars?

Tags: c#, string, list, recursion, permutation

So I was attempting a [challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5254ca2719453dcc0b00027d/csharp) on Codewars and after completing it, I saw the following solution.

```
 public static List<string> SinglePermutations(string s)
       => $"{s}".Length < 2 
          ? new List<string> { s } 
          : SinglePermutations(s.Substring(1))
                                .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(0, x.Length + 1)
                                .Select((_, i) => x.Substring(0, i) + s[0] + x.Substring(i)))
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList();
```

Could anyone explain this to me? I have seen the ternary operator and recursion before. I am relatively new to Select and Select many. However, putting all these into one question has confused me. Thanks!

Comment: Well, for one thing `$"{s}".Length` is just a really complicated way of saying `s.Length`. More suited for code golf I would think.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Comment: Whatever it is...it does not work. Tried it with a string "Jabberwocky" and it went into an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, `the two argument `Select` is just a really complicated way of saying `Select`, so `Enumerable.Range(0,x.Length+1).Select((_,i) =>` can be replaced with `Enumerable.Range(0,x.Length+1).Select(i =>`

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Doubt if it was an infinite loop - it just takes forever to compute the answer - it took my PC 19.26 seconds, and the result has 19,958,400 entries, though I am not sure that is right.

Comment: @NetMage uggg... wouldn't a better replacment be `"jabberwocky".ToCharArray()`?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan The answer is the list of all permutations of the characters in the string as a string - e.g. "this" -> "this", "htis", "hits", "hist", "tihs" and so on.

Comment: I think it is right - I forgot it throws out duplicates.

Comment: That `$"{s}".Length` is not identical to `s.Length`, because it also works when `s` is null. Not that I propose to do that this way...

Comment: @Evk Nice catch. However, I am going to go with C# 8 nullability and say `s` being `null` is illegal, since it's type isn't `string?` :)

Answer (score 2):

After simplifications I noted in my comments, here is some explanation:

```
public static List<string> SinglePermutations(string s)
       => s.Length == 1
              ? new List<string> { s } // a single character string only has one permuatation, itself
              : SinglePermutations(s.Substring(1)) // get all the permutations of the "tail" of the string i.e. the string minus the first char
                                                   // for each tail permutation
                    .SelectMany(aTailPermutation =>
                        // loop over all the positions in the permutation from before the first char to after the last char
                        Enumerable.Range(0, aTailPermutation.Length + 1)
                                  // for each position, put the original first char in that position
                                  .Select(i => aTailPermutation.Substring(0, i) + s[0] + aTailPermutation.Substring(i))
                    ) // flatten the resulting list of strings
                    .Distinct() // throw away any duplicates
                    .ToList(); // return as a list
```

It might be easier understood if converted to procedural code from LINQ:

```
public static List<string> SinglePermutationsFn(string s) {
    if (s.Length == 1)  // a single character string
        return new List<string> { s }; // only has one permuatation, itself
    else {
        var ans = new List<string>();

        // get all the permutations of the "tail" of the string i.e. the string minus the first char
        var tailPermutations = SinglePermutations(s.Substring(1));
        // loop over all the tail permutations
        foreach (var aTailPermutation in tailPermutations) {
            // loop over all the positions in the permutation from before the first char to after the last char
            for (int permutationPos = 0; permutationPos < aTailPermutation.Length + 1; ++permutationPos) {
                // for each position, put the original first char in that position
                ans.Add(aTailPermutation.Substring(0, permutationPos) + s[0] + aTailPermutation.Substring(permutationPos));
            }
        }
        return ans.Distinct() // throw away any duplicates
                  .ToList(); // return as a list
    }
}
```